# Determine the sign of local degrees formally

Tags: algebraic-topology

In an attempt to better understand the idea of using local degrees, I'm trying to compute $d_2$ in Example 2.39 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* in terms of local degrees (Hatcher himself refers the reader back to the $2$-d torus where he did not use local degrees).

Choosing a point $y$ in the $1$-cells $a$, it has two pre-images $x_1,x_2$ - one on the top edge and one on the bottom. I understand that since the two respective neighbourhoods of these $x_i$ (open intervals) are homeomorphically mapped to a neighbourhood of $y$ (open interval), then their degrees are necessarily $+/-1$.

Now my question is about determining the sign of each. I reasoned that since the top edge is a rotation composed with a reflection of the bottom edge, then they must have opposite signs (reflection flips the sign while rotation does not), and hence we get degree $0$ for the map to this $1$-cell $a$. **My problem is with how to make this more formal (degree of reflections and rotations are discussed for maps between two $S^n$, not between two edges. How does one make this degree analysis more rigorous? OR - how does one compute $d_2$ with degrees?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two maps $S^1 \to S^1$ are given by taking the boundary of the square and collapsing the complement of each edge. Since reflecting the square takes one (oriented) edge to the other, the two maps are related by the map reflecting the boundary of the square, which is the antipodal map on $S^1$.

But this has degree $-1$, so since degree of a composition is the product of the degrees, the two maps must have degrees $+1$ and $-1$ in some order, regardless of choices of orientation.

Comment: Thakns - are you able to make the first statement more formal? My problem is with the fact that the two edges are not actually $S^1$. It seems that we're identifying each edge as an $S^1$ which seems quite hand-wavy to me.

Comment: @Anon added some details

Comment: From the way Hatcher presents it - what we're collapsing is only in the $1$-skeleton $X^1$, not in the domain (which is the boundary of the $2$-dimensional disc we're attaching). Am I mistaken here?

Comment: Not for the local degree map, which is "collapse the complement of a disk neighborhood of the point" and is well-defined up to homotopy. We're just choosing the disk neighborhoods to be the (open) edges.

Comment: Thanks! I think I see it now - it's a consequence of the vertical isomorphisms appearing on p. 136 in Hatcher's book, correct?

Comment: Yes and that's more or less inevitable since that diagram defines local degree.